Installation problem on intel i5 7th gen laptop
Unable to install ubuntu LTS 24.04.1 on lenovo ideapad L340 , on installation process it bug report related to my pc ,even if i tend to continue installation on copying files or installing the system page it takes forever to finish it, How to install ubuntu successfully in this case ?

You give few specifics of the problem, only a very broad/vague overview... Ubuntu 24.04 LTS is available with 3 installers (subiquity, ubuntu-desktop-installer and calamares) and the main difference between them is just what packages get installed by default; so one option is always to download & use a different installer/ISO that may bypass your unknown issue  (once its installed; you can always just install & remove packages to make it what you want).  I assume you validated ISO, media check completed okay & you didn't have a procedural error in your prior approach...

BIOS or UEFI boot, shared with Windows or single operating system.

Have you updated UEFI firmware and if SSD its firmware. Lenovo Ideapad 320 Post #13 install without grub & then use Boot-Repair
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436555
Lenovo IdeaPad 5 PRO 16IHU6 - works like a charm
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2494154
Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15ALC05 with 22.04 works
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2468305&p=14113811#post14113811
Issues by brand often similar, so other version posts may have hints.

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 20.04 runs OK from USB but it takes too long to install on the HDD. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
